# CruiseControl.Net Failed Build - No explanation

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I am just beginning to set up a Continuous Integration Server using CruiseControl.Net. To keep things simple to begin with, I used the Visual Studio Task to carry out the build, pointing it at the project solution file. However, when the build process occurs, CC.Net successfully gets the latest source version from Subversion, and appears to run the devenv command. The build process then fails, but there is no explanation about why. Here is the output:

> **BUILD FAILED**
>   Project: MyProject
>   Date of build: 2009-09-09 16:31:13
>   Running time: 00:00:49
>   Integration Request: Dashboard triggered a build (ForceBuild)
>
> Modifications since last build (0)
>
> Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Not run: 0,
>   Time: 0 seconds   No Tests Run  This
>   project doesn't have any tests

There is nothing else displayed on the page. My XML Logs don't show any build results either.

This is my configuration file:

```
<!--<ccnetconfig><configurationVersion>1.4</configurationVersion></ccnetconfig>-->
<cruisecontrol>
  <project name="MyProject">
    <workingDirectory>C:\Users\Builder\Desktop\builder-pc\MyProject</workingDirectory>
    <sourcecontrol type="svn">
      <trunkUrl>svn://builder-pc/MyProject/trunk</trunkUrl>
      <workingDirectory>C:\Users\Builder\Desktop\builder-pc\MyProject</workingDirectory>
      <executable>C:\Program Files\Subversion\bin\svn.exe</executable>
      <autoGetSource>True</autoGetSource>
      <tagOnSuccess>True</tagOnSuccess>
    </sourcecontrol>
    <tasks>
      <devenv>
        <solutionfile>C:\Users\Builder\Desktop\builder-pc\MyProject\trunk\MyProject.sln</solutionfile>
        <configuration>release</configuration>
        <buildtype>Rebuild</buildtype>
        <executable>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe</executable>
        <buildTimeoutSeconds>600</buildTimeoutSeconds>
      </devenv>
    </tasks>
  </project>
</cruisecontrol>
```

I have deliberately removed things like the SVN username and password.

Building the solution using the VS Command Prompt works, albeit with warnings. This is using the same swtiches that CC.Net would be using.

Can anyone help? Is it failing because there are no unit tests to run, or because of the warnings? Or is it best to switch to MSBuild or NAnt instead of using the Visual Studio Task?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there is no useful information in the build log, try looking at the server log for information about the failure.

Comment: This solved the issue for me. I had a load of the paths set up incorrectly, and visual studio task was exiting saying it couldn't find the solution. This was in the server logs.

Answer (score 3):

I think the reason you aren't seeing any output in the xml log files is because you don't have an appropriate `<publishers>` section in your `<project>`.

Try:

```
<publishers>

  <xmllogger />

</publishers>
```

Comment: I did have this section but omitted it in the sample above.

Answer (score 1):

Try running the build with MSBuild instead of devenv.exe. If the log gets merged into the xml but is not displayed properly in the web dashboard, make sure that appropriate [xsl transforms](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/XSL+Files) are enabled. Also, as Scrappydog mentioned, add the xmllogger publisher (although it *should* be added by default if you don't have any publishers defined at all, you can check this in the 'Project Configuration' page on the dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **devnev.com** (note the file extension is **.com**, not .exe) in the same path (i.e. C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE), instead of devnev.exe.

The `<executable>` block is optional, and from [the CruiseControl.NET documentation](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Visual+Studio+Task), it will use the latest version of devnev.com, not devnev.exe.